# How to get email addresses of all users in liferay

Tags: java, liferay

I want to get email addresses of all users in liferay...
I have used the following code..

```
DynamicQuery dynamicQuery = UserLocalServiceUtil.dynamicQuery();
dynamicQuery.add(RestrictionsFactoryUtil.isNotNull("emailAddress"));
int startOfList = 0;
int endOfList = 100;
List<User> articles = (List<User>) UserLocalServiceUtil.dynamicQuery(dynamicQuery, startOfList, endOfList);
```

Can somebody tell me where am I doing mistake.

I am getting:

1. `java.lang.InstantiationException` and
2. `com.liferay.portal.kernel.deploy.hot.HotDeployException: Error registering portlets for ControlPanelPortlet-portlet`.

ControlPanelPortlet is the name of my portlet.

Comment: thank you for your help.. I am a newbie here..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code..

```
List<User> users = UserLocalServiceUtil.getUsers(0, UserLocalServiceUtil.getUsersCount());

for(User user : users) {
     System.out.println(user.getEmailAddress());
}
```

Let me know if you have some problem

Comment: You don't need to find the number of users (so is `UserLocalServiceUtil.getUsersCount()`) in order to get all users. Just use this: `UserLocalServiceUtil.getUsers(QueryUtil.ALL_POS, QueryUtil.ALL_POS)`

Answer (score 2):

If you want to fetch just the list of email-addresses of all the Users then you can use the following code:

```java
DynamicQuery dynamicQuery = UserLocalServiceUtil.dynamicQuery();

dynamicQuery.add(RestrictionsFactoryUtil.isNotNull("emailAddress"));

// this is the statement which would cause to return only a list of emails
dynamicQuery.setProjection(ProjectionFactoryUtil.property("emailAddress"));

int startOfList = QueryUtil.ALL_POS;

int endOfList = QueryUtil.ALL_POS; // this will fetch all the Users

// note: it returns a list of String
List<String> emailAddresses = (List<String>) UserLocalServiceUtil.dynamicQuery(dynamicQuery, startOfList, endOfList);
```

If you want to fetch the `User`s then you code is fine, just need to change the `startOfList` and `endOfList` field:

```java
DynamicQuery dynamicQuery = UserLocalServiceUtil.dynamicQuery();

dynamicQuery.add(RestrictionsFactoryUtil.isNotNull("emailAddress"));

int startOfList = QueryUtil.ALL_POS;

int endOfList = QueryUtil.ALL_POS;

List<User> users = (List<User>) UserLocalServiceUtil.dynamicQuery(dynamicQuery, startOfList, endOfList);
```

or if you don't want to check for any condition and want to fetch the `User`s then just use:

```java
List<User> users = UserLocalServiceUtil.getUsers(startOfList, endOfList);
```

And regarding the exceptions you are seeing, they are not related to the piece of code you have posted. These may due to some other code either in Java class or JSP. If you put the full stack-trace then may be we can help.

Comment: I didnt get the cause of these errors so i created a new java file and rewrite the code again.. Now its working fine.. Thank you for your help